# Navigating multiple screens in Linux

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I'm in a Linux terminal and created multiple screens.

When I try `screen -list`, I get the following:

```
prem@ubuntu:~$ screen -list
There are screens on:
    5110.work1  (11/15/2013 02:01:53 PM)    (Detached)
    4807.work1  (11/15/2013 01:54:11 PM)    (Attached)
    4621.work2  (11/15/2013 01:51:03 PM)    (Attached)
    2611.work1  (11/15/2013 11:31:56 AM)    (Attached)
4 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-prem.
```

But when I want to navigate to screen work1, I get the following:

```
prem@ubuntu:~$ screen -r work1
There are screens on:
        5110.work1      (11/15/2013 02:01:52 PM)        (Attached)
        4807.work1      (11/15/2013 01:54:10 PM)        (Attached)
        2611.work1      (11/15/2013 11:31:55 AM)        (Attached)
There is no screen to be resumed matching work1.
```

What does the -r command do here? Did it really navigate or how do I go to 5110.work1 screen and confirm its that screen?

Comment: I know it is not what you asked for, but have you tried `tmux`? You can attach into other sessions with `attach-session -t <name>`, the only drawback that I have noticed is the lack of support for serial ports, screen does have it, tmux does not.

Answer (score 2):

The -r option stands for `resume`. So your command means `resume the work session`, to which your pc is replying: there are multiple `work` session, which one do you mean?

The correct way to restart the second work session, for instance, is by means of

```
 screen -r 4807
```

and likewise for the other sessions. When you want to move to a different session, you again issue the usual command Ctrl a+ d, then select again the session you wish to move to. If you already know you want to move on to the next/previous session in the list, you use Ctrl a+n/Ctrl a+p, respectively.